# openssh setting on windows : Connection reset

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh, windows-10, ubuntu-16.04

I set up a (Ubuntu) virtual machine using Hyper-V on my Windows machine(Windows 10 Enterprise Edition OS) , but it seems my school network security rule does not allow me to share the internet to the VM, so I want to set up a ssh tunnel (to allow internet access on the VM for easy package installation using `apt install`).

I installed OpenSSH-Win64 on the windows machine. But when I try to connect from the ubuntu VM, it gives me error:

```
miranda@ubuntu-vm:~$ ssh -v 'cecs-030929\admin-u5214628'@150.203.213.249
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 150.203.213.249 [150.203.213.249] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/miranda/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/miranda/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/miranda/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/miranda/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/miranda/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/miranda/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/miranda/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/miranda/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 150.203.213.249:22 as 'cecs-030929\\admin-u5214628'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
Connection reset by 150.203.213.249 port 22
```

I don't know where to look. Some check from the Ubuntu VM:

```
miranda@ubuntu-vm:~$ tcpdchk
miranda@ubuntu-vm:~$ tcpdchk -v
Using network configuration file: (null)
miranda@ubuntu-vm:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5d:d5:f9:07
          inet addr:150.203.213.248  Bcast:150.203.213.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:5dff:fed5:f907/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:104320 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:369 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:16960579 (16.9 MB)  TX bytes:65010 (65.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:61438 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:61438 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:5382563 (5.3 MB)  TX bytes:5382563 (5.3 MB)
```

I have manually added a file `hosts.allow` in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` with the following content:

```
sshd: 150.203.213.248
```

It did not make any difference.

Comment: Take a look at tcpwrappers.

Comment: I'm not sure how to and what exactly to check, could you please give me more instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known issue, it's described here:

https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1027

Make sure you're a SYSTEM when you run sshd and collect logs.

Answer (score 0):

> Extract contents of the latest build to C:\Program Files\OpenSSH (Make sure binary location has the Write permissions to just to SYSTEM, Administrator groups. **Authenticated users should and only have Read and Execute**.)

In my case, after assigning "Read and Execute" permission for "Authenticated users", it works.

please refer to the installtion doc https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH#install-win32-openssh-test-release